# Email not send without any error (XAMPP)

Tags: php, email, xampp, gmail

I'm trying to send email only with **XAMPP** & **Gmail** without using **PHPMailer**
I tried to send email via Xampp and Gmail account.

I've activated Gmail account with 'less secure apps access'.

Also i had config the php.ini & sendmail.ini.

Somehow when i try send email it doesn't show any error message and the email was not sent.

Note: All is working well if using PHPMailer, but when i tried basic Xampp mailing is not working.

Here is my config and PHP code:

**php.ini**

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = myemail@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

**sendmail.ini**

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=587

smtp_ssl=auto

error_logfile=error.log

auth_username=myemail@gmail.com

auth_password=mypassword

force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
```

SendEmail.php

```
<?php
$to = "receiver@gmail.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: did u restart apache after configurations?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes i do

Comment: Need help here anyone can assist on this ?